# has_many through can not modify association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, nested

I have three models: Almon, Bela and Lingo

```
class Almon < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :bela, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :lingos, through: :bela, dependent: :delete_all

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bela
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :lingos, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

I am trying to submit a nested form in Almon and I am getting

> Cannot modify association 'Almon#Lingos' because the source reflection class 'Lingo' is associated to 'Bela' via :has_many.

Could anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please show your code

Comment: Is it clear enough now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use has_many instead of belongs_to as the following:

```
has_many :belaes, dependent: :destroy
has_many :lingoes, through: :belaes, dependent: :delete_all
```

Comment: Okay, this means i have to restructure the models. Thanks